# load more with jquery and a ajax string?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I'm working with a shopping script that makes it possible to load new products on the same page when you hit the bottom of the screen, like Facebook etc. 
It's possible to get an AJAX string for each page when you call the page like page1.ajax or page2.ajax. I've read numerous articles and tutorials but I can't figure this one out.

What I have so far is:

HTML

```
<div id="collection-ajax">
    <div class="productsGrid">
    // products on page 1 //
    </div>
    // WHEN CATEGORIE HAS MORE PAGES THIS HAVE TO BE SHOWN AFTER THE PRODUCTS ABOVE
    <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
```

The AJAX string (looks like json) and is one product the rest I let away:

```
{"page":1,"pages":2,"count":42,"url":"http:\/\/meules1.webshopapp.com\/woonkamer-en-keuken\/","products":[{"id":1750137,"vid":2765003,"image":"http:\/\/cdn.webshopapp.com\/i\/z1faly\/50x50x2\/newc.jpg","image_id":2156769,"brand":false,"code":"40-95407","ean":"40-95407","sku":"","score":false,"price":{"price":65,"price_money":"\u20ac65,00","price_money_with_currency":"\u20ac65,00 EUR","price_money_without_currency":"65,00","price_excl":54.6218,"price_excl_money":"\u20ac54,62","price_excl_money_with_currency":"\u20ac54,62 EUR","price_excl_money_without_currency":"54,62","price_incl":65,"price_incl_money":"\u20ac65,00","price_incl_money_with_currency":"\u20ac65,00 EUR","price_incl_money_without_currency":"65,00","price_old":109,"price_old_money":"\u20ac109,00","price_old_money_with_currency":"\u20ac109,00 EUR","price_old_money_without_currency":"109,00","price_old_excl":91.5966,"price_old_excl_money":"\u20ac91,60","price_old_excl_money_with_currency":"\u20ac91,60
```

The Jquery is the problem I'm facing. I personally thought something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var collectionPage  = {{ collection.page }};
var collectionPages = {{ collection.pages }};

function loadCollectionContent(){
    if(collectionPage < collectionPages){
        collectionPage++;  

        var url =  'http://shop.com/page' + collectionPage + '.ajax';

        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            var listItems = [];
            $.each(data.products, function(index, product){
                var itemHtml = '' 
                // HERE I'M STUCK ON WHAT TO DO NEXT
```

Can somebody point me to some directions? Or help me with the code? If you need more info let me know.

Comment: you can do something like this.

Comment: @vj shah: You mean mine approach would be a good one / working one?

Comment: yeah..work a little more.Else you can follow the other one too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this too.

```
$("loadmoreajaxloader").click(function(){ 
     //on clicking the bottom of page or whatever div you want
$.ajax({
    url:database_more.pl //fetch data 
    success:function(data){
       $("loadmoreajaxloader").html(data);
 //embed it in the current page whatever you obtain
     }
  });
});
```

Hope this helps. Still it's different from your approach.

Thanks.